# FFmpeg pad filter calculating wrong width

Tags: ffmpeg, filtering, pad

I'm using

```
ffmpeg.exe -i in.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]pad=iw:ih+10:0:0" out.jpg
```

to add a padding of `10px` at the bottom of images and videos.
In most cases it works as expected but with some the width is off by `1px` resulting in failure with error:

```
[Parsed_pad_0 @ 000002ba70617c40] Input area 0:0:623:640 not within the padded area 0:0:622:650 or zero-sized
[Parsed_pad_0 @ 000002ba70617c40] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_pad_0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

you can see that the width of the input area is `623` and the padded area width is `622` but this should not be the case since we are using `iw` to set the width of the padding.

Here is a sample image that fails.

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out you can not pad subsampled pixel formats at odd boundries.
the workaroud is to make the boundary even by using

```
ffmpeg.exe -i in.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil((ih+10)/2)*2:0:0" out.jpg
```